# How to pass foreign key manually in a join table for rails Has and belongs to many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models namely `Leave` and `Calendar`. These two models have has_and_belongs_to many association. I am trying to create the join table for this relation named `calendars_leaves`.

Now the problem that I am facing is it creates column named `leafe_id` instead of `leave_id`.

Any idea how to can I solve this issue.

Here are my models

```
class Leave < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :calendars, foreign_key: 'calendar_id'
  self.table_name = 'leaves'
  self.primary_key = 'leave_id'
end

class Calendar < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leaves, class_name: 'Leave', foreign_key: 'leave_id'

  validates :name, :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord resolves tables with 'ves' to singular model class with 'f' by default. Hence a table named `leaves` is resolved to ActiveRecord model class `Leaf`

So, for custom behaviour of these incorrect assumed translations, you need to configure it on your app's `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```

After configuring your app with this inflection and restarting your app's web server, rails will recognize `Leave` as the ActiveRecord model defined in `app/models/leave.rb` representing db table `leaves` and you can use `leave_id` as foreign key for defining associations between your models.

[Read more about inflections here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)